# Bus error disappears in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I have a large program in C that compiles fine, but when I run it (./a.out) I get: Bus error 10!
I used the gdb debugger to trace the memory error but the strange thing is that the program completes normally inside the gdb..Can this behaviour somehow be explained and how am I gonna debug my code now?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Comment: Try running it under valgrind instead of gdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some operating systems gdb will load the program differently in gdb. I know that on MacOS gdb will disable some address space layout randomization which changes how relocation of shared libraries is done. On some operating systems gdb will load more sections than a normal program execution or load those sections with wider permissions (non-executable memory might be executable under gdb or read-only will become writeable).

Your best bet is to catch a core dump of the problem and continue debugging from there. Valgrind is also good at catching this type of bugs.

Comment: The problem is actually only on MacOS. Valgrind is not working though in osx 10.8, so I will probably switch to a linux platform to avoid the fuss.